# Time out error message when running zeppelin notebook

Tags: java, pyspark, timeout, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

```
> %pyspark from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer from
> pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf from pyspark.sql.types import
> IntegerType
```

I'm trying to run this zeppelin notebook and this is the first block of code and I get this sizable error message.

> java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)  at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)    at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)    at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:228)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:449)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
>   java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)  at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)    at
>   java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)    at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)    at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:228)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:449)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Comment: Your stack trace seems to suggest that you're running Java 9 or newer. Have you tried this on java 8? (Looking at the [getting started page](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/quickstart/install.html), one can see that it supports and is tested on java 7.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm currently running into the same issue